# Swift: Stripe payment UI is not displaying properly in SwiftUI

Tags: uiviewcontroller, swiftui, stripe-payments

I am trying to show Stripe Payment UI of class ViewController inside SwiftUI but the  UI is not displaying properly

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit
import Stripe
import Alamofire


class CheckoutViewController: UIViewController {
   var setupIntentClientSecret: String?

     lazy var cardTextField: STPPaymentCardTextField = {
     let cardTextField = STPPaymentCardTextField()
     return cardTextField
       }()
   lazy var payButton: UIButton = {
      let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
       button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
       button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
       button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)
       button.setTitle("Save", for: .normal)
       button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pay), for: .touchUpInside)
      return button
   }()
lazy var emailTextField: UITextField = {
    let emailTextField = UITextField()
    emailTextField.placeholder = "Enter your email"
    emailTextField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
    return emailTextField
}()
lazy var mandateLabel: UILabel = {
    let mandateLabel = UILabel()
    mandateLabel.text = "I authorise Stripe Samples to send instructions to the financial institution that issued my card to take payments from my card account in accordance with the terms of my agreement with you."
    mandateLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    mandateLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .footnote)
    mandateLabel.textColor = .systemGray
    return mandateLabel
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [emailTextField, cardTextField, payButton, mandateLabel])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.spacing = 20
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(stackView)
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: view.leftAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        view.rightAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingAfter: stackView.rightAnchor, multiplier: 2),
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalToSystemSpacingBelow: view.topAnchor, multiplier: 2),
    ])
    
    HandlePayment().startCheckout()
}
}
```

I tried to convert the Viewcontroller to SwifUI using this

```
struct CheckoutViewControllerWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

  typealias UIViewControllerType = CheckoutViewController

  func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CheckoutViewControllerWrapper>) -> CheckoutViewControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType {
    return CheckoutViewController()
 }
func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: CheckoutViewControllerWrapper.UIViewControllerType, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<CheckoutViewControllerWrapper>) {
   
} }
```

and then call the UI with this in SwiftUI

```
 LCButton(text: "Add Payment") {

           self.showPaymentSheet = true
         }
                    
        .sheet(isPresented: $showPaymentSheet) {
            CheckoutViewControllerWrapper()
        }
```

this is what is displayed
[image: ui]

What is missing, I'm not sure why the UI is not displaying as the standard stripe integration UI

Comment: Might be addressed by https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/issues/1204

Comment: Did you get it working by any chance?